# Kann jemand diese Handschrift für mich lesen?

Tags: single-word-request

Weiß Raufaser
??? gestrichen

[image]

Danke für die Hilfe!

Comment: Diese Frage ist ein Service-request, die Bitte um eine Dienstleistung, deren Antwort keinem mit einer ähnlichen Frage weiterhelfen wird. Solche Fragen mögen einige zwar sehr gerne, weil sie grundsätzlich hilfsbereit oder ehrgeizig sind, aber sie passt formal nicht hier her. Vom scharfen S in "weiß" abgesehen ist daran auch nichts spezifisch deutsch, außer dass man sich mit Sprachpraxis beim Erraten unklarer Buchstaben natürlich leichter tut.

Comment: Sehe ich auch so und befürworte den close-Antrag. Was ich nicht gutheißen kann, ist der Downvote für die Antwort eines solchen hilfsbereiten Nutzers :-(

Answer (score 3):

Es heißt "schattig gestrichen". Vermutlich bedeutet das, dass eine Raufasertapete weiß gestrichen wurde, aber die Farbe nicht gleichmäßig aufgetragen wurde und dadurch einige Stellen dunkler wirken - wie Schatten.